# Changing object datasources at runtime

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to switch object datasources (objectdatasource1 and objectdatasource2) at runtime and refresh my reportviewer when button1 is clicked. I cant quite figure out how to do this and I am having trouble with getting the code below to work. Any ideas? Thank you

```
Dim dataSetName As String = "MyApplication_ModelObject"
        Dim ds As New MyApplication_ModelObjectTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapter()
        Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("MyApplication_ModelObject", ds.GetData())
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```